# Lifting a function to the top level causes compilation time to triple

Tags: performance, haskell, ghc, type-families

I'm using GHC 8.4.2 on Windows. I have this program that depends on the library [red-black-record](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record), version [2.0.2.2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.0.2.2):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeApplications #-}
module Main where

import Data.RBR (FromList,Delete,Variant,I,injectI,winnowI,match)

import GHC.TypeLits

type Phase01 = FromList '[ 
      '("ctor1",Int),   '("ctor2",Bool),  '("ctor4",Char),  '("ctor3",Char),
      '("ctor6",Char),  '("ctor5",Char),  '("ctor10",Char), '("ctor11",Char),
      '("ctor13",Char), '("ctor14",Char), '("ctor39",Char), '("ctor46",Char),
      '("ctor47",Char), '("ctor44",Char), '("ctor43",Char), '("ctor7",Char),
      '("ctor9",Char),  '("ctor20",Char), '("ctor45",Char), '("ctor21",Char),
      '("ctor48",Char), '("ctor49",Char), '("ctor50",Char), '("ctor41",Char),
      '("ctor33",Char), '("ctor32",Char), '("ctor42",Char), '("ctor22",Char),
      '("ctor23",Char), '("ctor8",Char),  '("ctor40",Char), '("ctor29",Char),
      '("ctor24",Char), '("ctor38",Char), '("ctor25",Char), '("ctor26",Char),
      '("ctor27",Char), '("ctor28",Char), '("ctor36",Char), '("ctor52",Char),
      '("ctor51",Char), '("ctor53",Char), '("ctor12",Char), '("ctor54",Char),
      '("ctor15",Char), '("ctor31",Char), '("ctor30",Char), '("ctor34",Char),
      '("ctor35",Char), '("ctor17",Char), '("ctor16",Char), '("ctor18",Char),
      '("ctor19",Char), '("ctor37",Char)
      ]

type Phase02 = Delete "ctor1" Int Phase01

main :: IO ()
main = print (match @"ctor17" (fromPhase1ToPhase2 (injectI @"ctor1" 2)))
    where
    fromPhase1ToPhase2 :: Variant I Phase01 -> Variant I Phase02
    fromPhase1ToPhase2 v = case winnowI @"ctor1" @Int v of 
        Right z -> injectI @"ctor2" False
        Left l -> l
```

(The library itself is not important, except as an example of code that makes heavy use of type families.)

This code takes **~ 9 seconds** to compile on my machine. But when I try to move the `fromPhase1ToPhase2` function out of the `where` clause and make it a top-level function, compilation time spikes to **~ 29 seconds**!

Is there a reason why lifting a function to the top level makes it compile slower?

**Edit:** as another data point, moving the function to the top-level but using `-XPartialTypeSignatures` like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-partial-type-signatures #-}

fromPhase1ToPhase2 :: Variant I _ -> Variant I _
fromPhase1ToPhase2 v = case winnowI @"ctor1" @Int @Phase01 v of 
    Right z -> injectI @"ctor2" False
    Left l -> l
```

keeps the original compilation time of **~ 9 seconds**.

Comment: The original compile time is already awful. I would recommend opening a ticket on the GHC trac, especially since this is a pretty small self-contained example.

Comment: When you moved `fromPhase1ToPhase2` to top level, did you also put its signature at top level? With a big type level list like `Phase01`, type inference (without a signature) is much harder than type checking (with a signature, even partial).

Comment: @AntC Yes, the ~ 29 seconds are with the top-level signature.

Comment: Opened GHC ticket https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/16382

Comment: It seems that the slowdown has to do with the example module's export list. If I write `module Main (main) where` instead of exporting everything, the slowdown disappears, even if the function `fromPhase1ToPhase2` is at top level. https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/16382#note_244810